# Animator's SetFloat method does not appear in Intellisense suggestions

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, intellisense

When I try to write `.SetFloat()` after `gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>()`, the Intellisense suggestions that appear don't include it. It also doesn't show SetBool, SetTrigger and other functions like that.

[image: Here is example image]

What might cause this issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Please make sure that the code you show here matches the code you have actually written. I was going to point out issues with `getcomponent` and `animator`, but your included image shows proper capitalization, which makes the answer likely much different.

Comment: Write once without autocompletation and see if it gives an error or not? If it gives an error, the problem is with the Unity project, if it does not give an error, the problem is with the compiler.

Comment: Please stop spamming the same question like you did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72510609/animators-setfloat-method-does-not-appear?noredirect=1)